# Watin - BringToFront() not working

Tags: c#, watin

I'm having the difficulties to use watin bringtofront function. It just doesn't bring my browser to the front - someone please shed me some light on it.
Here's my code:

```
    public bool GenerateReport(string rptPath, string rptName)
    {
        var popupTitle = new Regex("Crystal Reports ActiveX");
        var popUpBrowser = WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle(popupTitle));

        if (popUpBrowser != null)
        {
            var result = false;
            try
            {
                popUpBrowser.AutoClose = false;
                popUpBrowser.BringToFront();
                popUpBrowser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.ShowMaximized);                    
                popUpBrowser.DialogWatcher.CloseUnhandledDialogs = false;
                result = ExportPdfFile(popUpBrowser, rptPath + rptName + RptExt);
            }
            finally
            {
                popUpBrowser.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging using a breakpoint on that line of code? If so, can you provide the details from it?

Comment: hey there, what sort of details are you seeking ? Any property in particular ?